# c++ compile one central library with additional static libraries, and main exe link only with the central one

Tags: c++, static-libraries, static-linking

i have central static lib in app that is windows simple executable.
now this center lib is just central point to using other helper library's im using 
what i try to do is , to link statically all static library's into this static central lib 
and then im my executable only link statically with this central lib .
for example :
i have this central static lib

```
#ifndef _HellperLib_H
#define _HellperLib_H

namespace HellperLib
{
    class HellperLib
    {
        public:
            HellperLib();
            ~HellperLib();
            void invokeRequest();
        private:
    };
};
#endif



#include "HellperLib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

namespace HellperLib
{

    HellperLib::HellperLib()
    {
        ;
    }

    HellperLib::~HellperLib()
    {

    }

    void HellperLib::invokeRequest()
    {
          CURL *curl;
          CURLcode res;

          curl = curl_easy_init();
          if(curl) {
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
            /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */ 
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

            /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
            res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
            /* Check for errors */ 
            if(res != CURLE_OK)
              fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                      curl_easy_strerror(res));

            /* always cleanup */ 
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
          }
    }

}
```

as you can see its simple lib that is using curl static lib.

now i have another app that is executble tester

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "HellperLib.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    HellperLib::HellperLib hellperLib;
    hellperLib.invokeRequest();
    return 0;
}
```

to it i just add in the linker the hellperLib.lib file and path 
but the linker yield me error:

```
1>HellperLib.lib(HellperLib.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_strerror referenced in function "public: void __thiscall HellperLib::HellperLib::invokeRequest(void)" (?invokeRequest@HellperLib@1@QAEXXZ)
1>HellperLib.lib(HellperLib.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_init referenced in function "public: void __thiscall HellperLib::HellperLib::invokeRequest(void)" (?invokeRequest@HellperLib@1@QAEXXZ)
1>HellperLib.lib(HellperLib.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_setopt referenced in function "public: void __thiscall HellperLib::HellperLib::invokeRequest(void)" (?invokeRequest@HellperLib@1@QAEXXZ)
1>HellperLib.lib(HellperLib.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_perform referenced in function "public: void __thiscall HellperLib::HellperLib::invokeRequest(void)" (?invokeRequest@HellperLib@1@QAEXXZ)
1>HellperLib.lib(HellperLib.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_cleanup referenced in function "public: void __thiscall HellperLib::HellperLib::invokeRequest(void)" (?invokeRequest@HellperLib@1@QAEXXZ)
```

that means i need to add the curl static lib to the executable tester , and this i want to avoid if possible .

Comment: Visual Studio does not have the concept of Convenience Libraries.

Comment: If you make central lib a DLL linking to these externals will be done in the dll only.

Comment: i need to find static lib solution

Comment: With a static central lib in Visual Studio I believe the best you can do is use #pragma comment(lib ...) in the header for the central lib. This way you do not have to specify the libs in the exe manually.

Comment: sound like good solution and in Linux/MAC what will be the replacement ?

Comment: I would use [convenience libraries](http://www.sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_92.html)

Comment: An alternate option is to use a cross platform project file generator like CMake where if your users accept using CMake (many will still want the native system) all of the external library handling will be done for them with CMake.